# Is there a MySQL Processor or REST API for Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I'd suppose there is some sort of MySQL REST API or a processor included with the Orbeon 3.9 PE. However I seem to fail in finding any documentation about such.

If there's some generic solution available for doing CRUD operations for xforms data, it would be nice to have some document on ho to use it.

So the question is, is there any?
Or should I just write my own custom REST API/processor?
(I need it to be able to handle form data from more than just on form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orbeon Forms provides a [REST persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api) for MySQL and other databases. That API is designed to be used by forms created with Form Builder. You can use it from a form you write "by hand" (editing XForms in your editor), but since the API was designed to be used in the context of forms created by Form Builder, it may or may not satisfy your requirements. In particular, when going through that API, data is stored [in pre-defined tables](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers#TOC-MySQL).

If this API doesn't satisfy your requirements, you can implement your own, either using Orbeon 
technologies (page flow, pipelines, and the [SQL processor](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-sql)), or using any other technology (PHP, servlet…).

Comment: The SQL processor is probably the one I need. By the way, the links on REST persistence API to "Oracle/MySQL persistence layer" are both broken. http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Built-in-persistence

Comment: Thanks, I fixed those broken links.